# OSX Yosemite change sound output while headphones plugged in

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, headphones, sound-volume

I've a problem which is my headphones' jack is broken into my computer. I can't hear any voice neither from headphones nor from internal speakers.

What I need is, to hear some sound from internal speakers while my headphones' jack is broken in my computer.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: see the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6Mt4edcCUs

Comment: What model macbook pro?

Comment: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a Macbook Pro with only one jack input (no separate inputs for microphone/headphones), try alt (option) clicking the Sound Menu in the menu bar and selecting "Use Audio port for" -> Input. This way the system will think that you want to use what's plugged in as microphone and not as headphones and you will be able to use the speakers once again.

[image: Audio menu]

Comment: I've only one jack input, but there's no "Use Audio port for:" part. Is there anywhere I can turn it on/off

Comment: http://imgur.com/IH9o7lR

Comment: It seems that your computer is stuck on "Digital output". How is the minijack stuck inside the Mac? Can you post a photo?

Comment: I have the same problem. No "use audio port for" section. I came here because my headphone jack broke off in the computer, and I want to be able to use my computer's speakers again, otherwise I have no sound.

Answer (score 0):

Just pull the headphone jack from computer out a few times very quickly.

Comment: it is broken inside, how can I pull it?

Answer (score 0):

What's unclear from your initial question, is, if something is physically stuck in your headphone jack, or if you just assume "it is broken" because you can no longer hear sound from your internal speakers.

If a headphone cable broke and a physical part is remaining inside the headphone jack, you need to remove that part. There are several ways to go about that. I was once able to grab a stuck part with a very small forceps.

There's a known issue where MacBook Pros think, an optical cable is connected to the headphone jack although that is not true. In that case, insert a headphone jack and remove it again (this may take up to 1 or 2 minutes) but eventually your internal speakers will come back on, once the MacBook understands that nothing is connected to the headphone jack. If your MacBook indeed thinks there's an optical cable connected, you'll see a red light in that headphone jack.